# Can not generate pdf which has chart in wkhtmltopdf with chart version :3.3.0

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

i have a chart which is supported in version chart js version 3.3.0 and i am using wkhtmltopdf version (wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt))
when i execute

```
wkhtmltopdf -R 0 -L 0 -T 0 -B 0 --debug-javascript report.html report.pdf
```

i am not getting the chart in the pdf and
i am getting this kind of response
[image]

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.0:7 SyntaxError: Parse error

but html is working fine
i have also figured out that wkhtmltopdf uses qt browser tool which do not support the js syntax which are used in chart.js@3.3.0

any work around ??